# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 C Program Exception

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I am using Microsoft Visual Stusio 2013 Community Edition Update 4 to write a program in the C programming language (not C++). Whenever I try to build and run my program, partway through execution it tells me "Unhandled exception at 0x52873FD4 (msvcr120d.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00C40000." When I copy and paste the contents of the .c file into another IDE (code blocks) it compiles and runs without a problem. (Although I do have to change all the `scanf_s` statements in the code to `scanf`)

The source code from within the .c file of my program

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846;

double add();
double cos_d_r();
double div();
double mult();
void list();

int main()
{
    //Declaration of variables
    char oper[20];
    double ans;
    int loop = NULL;

    //While loop allows for multiple executions without restarting program
    while (!loop)
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter a mathematical operation.\n\nFor a list of options, enter 'list'\n\n");
        scanf_s(" %s", oper);

        //If statement to determine which operation to do

        //Addition
        if (strcmp(oper, "add") == 0 || strcmp(oper, "addition") == 0 || oper[0] == '+')
        {
            ans = add();
            printf("The sum is %.2f\n", ans);
        }

        //Cosine
        else if (strcmp(oper, "cos") == 0 || strcmp(oper, "cosine") == 0)
        {
            ans = cos_d_r();
            printf("The cosine of the angle is %lf\n", ans);
        }

        //Division
        else if (strcmp(oper, "divide") == 0 || strcmp(oper, "division") == 0 || oper[0] == '/')
        {
            ans = div();
            printf("The quotient is %.2f\n", ans);
        }

        //List of possible operations
        else if (strcmp(oper, "list") == 0)
        {
            list();
        }

        //Multiplication
        else if (strcmp(oper, "multiply") == 0 || strcmp(oper, "multiplication" == 0) || oper[0] == '*')
        {
            ans = mult();
            printf("The product is %.2f", ans);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//Declaration of functions

//Addition
double add()
{
    double ans;
    double num_1;
    double num_2;

    puts("Enter the first number");
    scanf_s(" %lf", &num_1);
    puts("Enter the second number");
    scanf_s(" %lf", &num_2);
    ans = num_1 + num_2;
    return ans;
}

//Cosine
/*Uses cos() function from math.h
this function adds option for degrees or radians*/
double cos_d_r()
{
    char deg_rad;
    double angle;
    double ans;
    int loop = NULL;

    while (!loop)
    {
        puts("Degrees or radians? Enter 'd' or 'r'");
        scanf_s(" %c", &deg_rad);

        //Degrees
        if (deg_rad == 'd')
        {
            puts("Enter an angle in degrees");
            scanf_s(" %lf", &angle);
            angle = angle / 180 * PI;
            ans = cos(angle);
            loop = 1;
            return ans;
        }

        //Radians
        else if (deg_rad == 'r')
        {
            puts("Enter an angle in radians");
            scanf_s(" %lf", &angle);
            ans = cos(angle);
            loop = 1;
            return ans;
        }

        //Else statement repeats loop if user enters text other than 'd' or 'r'
        else
        {
            puts("ERROR. Enter either 'd' or 'r'");

        }
    }
}

//Division
double div()
{
    double ans;
    double num_1;
    double num_2;

    puts("Enter the dividend");
    scanf_s(" %lf", &num_1);
    puts("Enter the divisor");
    scanf_s(" %lf", &num_2);
    ans = num_1 / num_2;
    return ans;
}

//Multiplication
double mult()
{
    double ans;
    double num_1;
    double num_2;

    puts("Enter the first number");
    scanf_s(" %lf", &num_1);
    puts("Enter the second number");
    scanf_s(" %lf", &num_2);
    ans = num_1 * num_2;
    return ans;
}

//List of possible operations
void list()
{
    printf("The possible operations are:\n\n");
    printf("Operation\tDescription\tCommand");
    printf("Addition\tAdds two numbers together\tAdd, Addition, +\n");
    printf("Cosine\tFinds the cosine of the angle entered\tCos, Cosine");
    printf("Division\tDivides the first number by the second\tDivide, Division, /");
    printf("Multiplication\tMultiplies the two numbers\tMultiply, Multiplication, *");
}
```

Comment: You almost certainly have a bug in your code. You'll have to track it down. You may wish to use a debugger.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I tried using the debugger in visual studio and all it does is run through the code until that message pops up again. Could it have something to do with the compiler?

Comment: @DavidPostill I apologize for being off topic, I had originally thought that the problem was with the program I was using, not the code itself.

Comment: Line 56: strcmp(oper, "multiplication" == 0) ?

Comment: @YongyiChen Minor syntax error, didn't affect the issue when fixed

Comment: But that's what made it crash for me, after fixing it, no more crash...

Comment: @YongyiChen Are you getting the "Unhandled exception" error

Comment: No, but I don't know what inputs you gave.

Comment: @user3308082, I think you need to read the documentation for [`scan_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), especially regarding scanning strings.

Comment: run it under the debugger (press F5), VS should stop where the error is and highlight the failing line. If it doesnt then single step through the program (F10) till it goes bang

Comment: In Visual Studio I think from the Debug menu there should be something about Exceptions which should allow you to turn on immediate stop on an access violation exception.  I believe the default is to not do an immediate stop so if you turn that on then as soon as the exception happens, you will see a break and should be able to look at the stack to see where the problem is and be able to look at variables and such.

Comment: `int loop = NULL;`? `NULL` is for pointers. Also it's bad form and potentially troublesome to name your functions the same as standard ones, like `div()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read description of functions you use first! Take a look at [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w40768et.aspx) function description at MSDN. You programm crashes at first call of this function

```
scanf_s(" %s", oper);
```

The correct way to use it:

```
scanf_s("%s", oper, _countof(oper)); // or sizeof(oper), but only with char array
```

Also you should correct other calls of `scanf_s` in your code. (Or disable errors for `scanf` call with `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before `#include <stdio.h>`)